# Schema.org: using ImageGallery with ImageObject?

Tags: semantic-web, image-gallery, microdata, schema.org

I've started to use schemas from [schema.org](http://schema.org/) in my HTML code and have prepared an image gallery (snippet below).  When I pasted my code into [Google Structured Data Testing Tool](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets), I received no errors, thus I assumed my way use of these schemas was proper, but am still if it is.  Is it?

```xml
<figure itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageGallery">
  <figcaption itemprop="description">The castle through the ages: 1423, 1858, and 1999 respectively.</figcaption>
  <figure itemprop="image" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
    <figcaption itemprop="caption">Etching. Anonymous, ca. 1423.</figcaption>
    <a href="castle1423.jpeg" itemprop="contentURL"> <img src="castle1423_thumb.jpeg" alt="The castle has one tower, and a tall wall around it." itemprop="thumbnailUrl"> </a> </figure>
  <figure itemprop="image" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
    <figcaption itemprop="caption">Oil-based paint on canvas. Maria Towle, 1858.</figcaption>
    <a href="castle185.jpeg" itemprop="contentURL"> <img src="castle1858_thumb.jpeg" alt="The castle now has two towers and two walls." itemprop="thumbnailUrl"> </a> </figure>
  <figure itemprop="image" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
    <figcaption itemprop="caption">Film photograph. Peter Jankle, 1999.</figcaption>
    <a href="castle1999.jpeg" itemprop="contentURL"> <img src="castle1999_thumb.jpeg" alt="The castle lies in ruins, the original tower all that remains in one piece." itemprop="thumbnailUrl"> </a> </figure>
</figure>
```

Comment: Do you have some reason to think that it isn't?

Comment: In my opinion that way of use of those schemas is proper. I asked my question, because I wanted to have bigger picture of that issue by some kind of 'brainstorming' with people who have more practice with web semantics than myself.

Comment: If the validator does not give you errors, your code is probably correct enought without looking at it. Check the output of the testing tool to make sure Google sees what you expect them to.

Comment: @infralabs How you describe what you are looking for is not what this platform is for. We don't brainstorm here, we solve issues you may have. This is why you dont  get any answers. Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask  
To answer the qustion at hand, you have no problem with the markup you have done but you could include more information, like name, description and so on..

Comment: Thank you for all your answers.

Comment: @ErikLandvall I must admit using a word 'brainstorming' was too ambiguous. Despite of no errors from Google's validator, I was not sure about my of using schema.org, because I hadn't found nor in google and on stackoverflow similar examples to mine. My intention was to get some feedback that my way of thinking/working with schema.org is correct or not. Regards.

Comment: @infralabs I would enjoy such a discussion, but this is as stated not the place. I have wrote a search engine and indexation bot my self and we are using schema.org as a fundamental thinking of how to look at content. The only suggestion I can give you is to mark up as much information as possible. It's the information we look for to be able to index your content accordingly. If this is all the information you wish to give then there is nothing more for you to mark up.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about whether usage of a particular schema vocabulary is correct or not.  This will lead to a discussion about the semantics of the schema, as the syntax is already known to be correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`image` property](http://schema.org/image) of [`ImageGallery`](http://schema.org/ImageGallery) a) expects an URL, and b) is defined as:

> URL of an image of the item.

So your markup says: "*My ImageGallery can be described by three images.*"; while it probably should say: "*My ImageGallery consists of three images.*".

So with `image` you could specify an image that can be used to represent the whole gallery.

For each image of the gallery you should probably use the [`associatedMedia` property](http://schema.org/associatedMedia) (but I’m not 100% sure if I get its definition correctly, "encode" confuses me here).

The markup for each [`ImageObject`](http://schema.org/ImageObject) looks good to me.

Comment: This is the kind of answer I expected. You helped me to understand it better.
I think that replacing `itemprop="image"` with `itemprop="associatedMedia"` is much proper, especially that `image` refers to a string and `associatedMedia` to the object (in this case: `MediaObject`).